# override specifier as template parameter - is it valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-bug

I have the following piece of code that does not compile under Visual C++ 2015, but does under GCC 4.8.4. I'm wondering which is right? The code in question is here below:

```
template <class T> class ATemplate;
template <class R, class A1>
    struct ATemplate<R(A1)>{ };

int main()
{
    ATemplate<void(int)> x;
//    ATemplate<void(int)override> y; //---Does not compile!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Is it wrong to use **override** as specifier here below (or const). Similar code exists in the GMock library, where macro expansion is used to generate the template parameter (including override), as well as the actual function signature.

Visual C++ 2015 produces the following error when removing the commented out line:

```
x.cpp(11): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
x.cpp(11): error C2976: 'ATemplate': too few template arguments
x.cpp(4): note: see declaration of 'ATemplate'
x.cpp(11): error C2079: 'y' uses undefined class 'ATemplate'
```

One of the answers below mention that **override** is meaningless in the context of free functions (valid point) - does this mean GCC is wrong here. The **const specifier** is also meaningless in that case (for free functions), but nevertheless permitted (by VC++)??? Also, it mentions that virtual specifiers should only exists in the declaration - this makes no difference to this case (as no definition exists). For the virtual keyword, it is OK to ommit in the derived as it makes no difference to whether code compiles, but for the override case it is not OK as it makes a big difference.

When using *ReturnType (ArgType arg) ...possible const or override specifier* as a macro parameter (like GMock does), the restriction imposed by VCC causes this code not to compile (apparently the case for Clang too). Which is right?

The standard does not state that the override specifier shall not be used in this context (the context of a template parameter?), does it?

Comment: Judging by the votes I'm probably missing something obvious, but where's the function you want to override?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that's irrelevant

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, yes, that is irrelevant. The code posted is minimal and produces the error.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath.  I've also added the error produced - my apologies for not doing that prior.

Comment: It's a g++ bug. The standard permits *virt-specifier-sec* in two productions: in a *function-definition* (only for virtual member function definitions) and in a *member-declarator*. Your context is neither.

Comment: @n.m. If you add it as formal answer (also noting that it is a gcc bug), I will mark this as the correct answer and submit a bug (if it has not been submitted yet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a g++ bug.

The standard permits *virt-specifier-sec* in two productions: in a function-definition (only for `virtual` *member-function* definitions) and in a *member-declarator*. Your context is neither.

A shorter demo of GCC's buggy behaviour:

```
void foo(void) override;          // g++ rejects with message: 
                                  //  virt-specifiers in 'foo' 
                                  //  not allowed outside a class definition
void (*bar)(void) override;       // g++ erroneously accepts
typedef void baz(void) override;  // g++ erroneously accepts
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the standard the `override` specifier is context-sensitive and has special meaning **only** when it's used **after a member function** declaration; otherwise, it's not a reserved keyword.

So i would say, the code in your second example seems meaningless.

I tried compiling your both examples with `gcc-5.1.0` (with the -S flag) and they result in exactly the same assembly.

It does not compile under `clang-3.7.0` resulting in the following error:

```
test.cpp:11:23: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
```

Pracitcally it means you should not use override in that way.

Comment: what does this mean practically in the context here above?

Comment: @WernerErasmus it means you should not use it like that :)

Comment: @WernerErasmus I agree. I ll remove the example, however the fact that you should use the specifier after member functions only, holds true.

Comment: Therefore you agree that this is a gcc bug? I can show you code where the example is not entirely meaningless. This is the expression that originally caused the headache (using gmock): 

MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(fileExists, bool(const Path& pathFileName) override);

Answer (score 2):

From *9.2 Class members* (draft N4140)

```
virt-specifier-seq:
    virt-specifier
    virt-specifier-seq virt-specifier
virt-specifier:
    override
    final
```

[9.2/8]

> A *virt-specifier-seq* shall contain at most one of each *virt-specifier*. A *virt-specifier-seq* shall appear only in
>   the declaration of a virtual member function (10.3).

So as far as I can see, `override` can not be applied to free functions, so I wouldn't expect it to be allowed in the signature/type of a free function (even if it was part of the type like `const`).

Comment: override in the context here above is not appearing in the definition of the function (as I've not specified a definition), but I see your point - Nevertheless, omitting virtual in the derived case does not matter, but omitting override does, therefore this cannot be treated the same.

Comment: @WernerErasmus not quite what I meant, edited for clarification (I hope :) )